# Spring rabbit message consumption, payload wrong format

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am consuming messages from a queue in rabbitmq like that

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = "#{'${rabbitmq.queues}'.split(',')}" )
public void processOrder(@Payload String data, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue) {
```

The data I am printing in my logger seems to be bytes, it is printing values like that: 116,104,114,116,104,114,116,104,114
What am I supposed to do and how please? Deserialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `SimpleMessageConverter` can only handle String and serialized Java objects. Any content type it doesn't understand is returned as a byte[].

The `content_type` for a String should be `text/plain`.

What is the content of your message? Does the message have a `content_type` property? If so, what value?

If it's JSON (and `application/json`) you need a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`, but I see you expecting String, so I suspect it's just the missing `content_type` property.

Comment: Actually the payload is in json format. To test, I just used the web interface of rabbitmq to publish a message and as you suggested I added the content_type that was missing. So I still need the _Jackson2JsonMessageConverter_. Where should I add this conversion please?

Comment: I have found it, I just have to modify the function arguments as 'public void processOrder( Message message, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue ) {'